# I can't post a comment which contains code in which many times @ symbol is used

Tags: discussion, comments

I have some SQL Server T-SQL code which I need to comment on my post and which also contains so many `@symbols` in it because of which I am not able to post my comment.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255)

EXEC @cmd = master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp Charu.dbo.Branch 
                     IN "D:\Charu\Export.xlsx" -U Charu.goyal -T -c'

SELECT @cmd
```

Comment: Generally it's not a very good idea to post code in comments.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Also, comments don't support newline, so it'd be hard to read SQL codes in one single line.

Answer (score 6):

You can mark your code like this (`code`) by wrapping it with backtick (`` ` ``) characters.

As you can see in my comment below this answer:

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `@Hallo @Hallo @Hallo @Hallo @Hallo` use "`" in the beginning and in the end of your code